# how to create a multi war war module ?

Tags: java, maven, module, war, multiple-inheritance

I would like to create a multi module project where more than one module is of type war. for example

```
<module>somejars</module>
<module>servletsAndJsps</module>
<module>springMVCapp</module>
<module>angularJsApp</module>
```

3 of those would work independly as WAR apps, but when I run mvn install command on parent it would create a super app that contains all 3 apps. web.xml's would be somehow merged or parent web.xml would be used.

please help

Comment: You should look at the different packaging types java offers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file. I guess you are looking for an ear-packaging which allows to pack multiple wars and jars for deployment for an application server.

Comment: no, i'm not looking for ear

Comment: Can you show use your pom files, cause it sounds a little bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

When you run maven install on your multimodule project the maven reactor plugin will by default run install on parent project and then on the 3 or 4 sub module projects. Since you want to club all three wars together I would suggest create one more sub module named **clubbedWars**

```
<module>somejars</module>
<module>servletsAndJsps</module>
<module>springMVCapp</module>
<module>angularJsApp</module>
<module> clubbedWars </module>
```

Now add all the other modules as dependeny in this module clubbedWars. This module’s install will get run last after all other modules install has run.  Now simply use copy-dependency and assembly plugin of maven in this module to club all these three wars together and install them in clubbedWars war or zip.