# Not able to add the Spring jars into EAR under Tomcat Server. note :i added those in WEBINF/lib

Tags: classpath

i have added all the jars  into WEBINF/lib  but it is not added into my EAR,
When i add EAR to TOMCAT server i am seeing only one jar,

WEBINF/lib:
all my spring jars,

Tomcat V7.0
->MySpringExampleEAR
->only one jar

so i am getting below exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner in eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32.

I have tried by using Deplyoment assembly.Still am getting the same exception

Currrently not able to attach Image.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?
Is there any solution other than MAVEN deploy for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [.war vs .ear file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file/1594818#1594818)

Tomcat does not handle .ear files, only .war files.

If you are using Maven to create a web app that is intended to be deployed to Tomcat, do not use the maven ear plugin.