# Internel URL for .ear file deployment

Tags: url, servlets, ear

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file) JAR and WAR are packeged in EAR file.
I have a Java Servlet packaged and a `index.html` that uses Angular.js to send HTTP requests to the Servlet, here is my URL (running on localhost, using Tomcat).

```
var baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/GM/deploy  //GM - my project name
```

And in the servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/deploy")
```

My question is, after deploying my EAR file on WebShpere, what is the URL that goes inside `baseUrl`? Is there a way to send the request using relative path?

Comment: Your question is confusing. URLs have got nothing to do with EARs. Perhaps your actual concern is the dynamicness of WAR's context path? In that case, is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4764405

Comment: My question is : how to get from my javascript file to the servlet ?

Comment: I didnt notice the link, it looks like that what I was looking for.