# How to package my jar file as wildly war file?

Tags: jboss, war, wildfly, ear

I have a jar file which takes some input from command line and does processing. I want to make this jar file as a deployable war file (wildly file) How can i do that? Any guide would be appreciated.
(I have installed jobs tools in my eclipse,)

And I would like to know the difference between ear file and the war file? Any detail explanation would be appreciated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.war vs .ear file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure a command line application makes much sense in a web container. That said in a WAR libraries need to go in the `WAR/WEB-INF/lib` directory.