# What are the steps I need to do in order to deploy 3 wars clubbed in a single war?

Tags: java, maven

I have three maven projects which are being deployed as individual war but I need to make one of them as my master war and the other two inside it. I don't want to change file structure.
Is it possible and if so, what would be the steps to achieve it.

Comment: In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie. 
One [Ear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file) to rule them all, 
One Ear to find them, 
One Ear to bring them all, 
and in the darkness bind them.

Comment: But i don't want one EAR to rule them all. I want WAR

Comment: You say that, but then you don't want to change the file structure of what you have (which is?); when you say the other two "inside it" that implies some kind of nesting and it isn't possible to embed one war in another (and you want two). Whereas, if you put all three war files in an ear, they can operate (potentially) without any other changes. Of course, apart from adding metadata files, an ear is a war is a jar is a zip file.