# How can we create a war file contaning a bundle of application?

Tags: java

How can we create a single war file for multiple or diif application code and deoply on single  aws enviornment?

Comment: What type of project do you have? maven? sbt? There are different ways in which you can do this for each type of projects.

Comment: maven .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `pom.xml` to create war file later to be deployed anywhere!

```
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains in general terms how to create a WAR file in Maven.

However you are asking how to create a WAR file for *"multiple or diff[erent] application code"*.  The answer depends on what you mean.

- If you mean a single webapp that has multiple components and / or dependencies, then the accepted answer should work.
- If you mean a multiple webapps ... there is a problem.  A WAR contains a single webapp.  There is only one `WEB-INFO` tree and only one `web.xml` file in a WAR file.  So your options are:

  - Create and deploy multiple WAR files.
  - Try to integrate the separate webapps into a single webapp.  This could be as simple as rewriting the `web.xml` files and combining the WEB-INFO trees.  Or it could be more complicated.  Then create the WAR for the combined webapp.
  - If your web container supports this, you could create and deploy an EAR file containing multiple webapps; see [.war vs .ear file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file)