# Application Context & Servlet Path for 2 Apps Loaded in Tomcat Webapps directory

Tags: java

I have deployed two apps in web-apps directory

say

```
1. http://server.com/app1
2. http://server.com/app2
```

When a request has been hit from the client, it would be routed to to app1 or app2 based on the URL.

Both of them are spring application which has been deployed to the same server.

```
Question:
  1. Does Both Apps have different application context or same application context?
  2. If i get the application context via ServletRequestContext will i get one or multiple?
  3. What would be the servlet path for the above apps ?
```

My understanding:

```
1. Both cannot run on the same tomcat with same port
2. Both of them have their own application context
3. Both are completely independent application
4. Both have their IOC containers separately
5. Even if one is down, the other would be running as long as tomcat is 
   not killed
```

Thanks.